# null check for hashmap key

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a scenario where I need to check for `null`. I have a key named `dT`:

```
String dT = (String) caseChk.get("dT");
```

This throws a `NullPointerException`, since that key itself doesn't exist. If I check with

```
if(caseChk.get("dT") != null) {
    // do something
}
```

yet another `NullPointerException` is thrown because of `.get`. How can I test for `null` when a key in the map doesn't exist? I understand that the `put` method should handle it, but that isn't under my control.]

Comment: caseChk is not null. "dT' doesnt exists in caseChk for specific scenarios. So i should chk for the key i beleive.

Comment: The only possible reason for this line `if(caseChk.get("dT") != null)` to throw a NPE is that `caseChk` is `null`...

Comment: Hashmaps dont throw a NPE if the key doesn't exist. It returns null in that case. You are getting NPE because caseChk is null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Even now I get nullpoiner since .get throws exception

If `caseChk.get("dT")` is only line you have there and sure it is throwing exception, then only possibility is `caseChk` could be null.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure key exists you should use `HashMap#containsKey(key)` function. Once key exists you may use `HashMap#get(key)` to get the value and compare it to null.

Answer (score 0):

caseChk coud be null try this

```
 String dT;
if(chaseChk!= null) 
dT= (String)caseChk.get("dT");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the method to check null

public String checkNull_HashMap(Hashtable hashMap, String hashKey) {

```
    if (hashMap.get(hashKey) == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return hashMap.get(hashKey).toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to check for null before calling `toString()`

```
if ( hashMap.get(hashKey) != null ) { return hashMap.get(hashKey).toString(); }
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to the example provided by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work.

```
    if(!caseChk.isEmpty)
    {
      String dT = (caseChk.containsKey("dT")?(String)caseChk.get("dT"):" ")
    }
```